# How to change the node/add modal form css

Tags: 8, forms, chaos-tool-suite

I'm using the drupal modal system to create popups to add content, Hello, I'm working in a D8 project.
The problem is that with the ajax the system add a width of 300px to the modal window, and I'd like to change it.

I don't see how to change this style, only try a diferent css with important attribute.

Any other way?

Comment: How are you actually adding the modal? Programatically or via a module? If programatically you can set it via an attribute on the trigger: `data-dialog-options='{"width":"500"}'`